# Vim Not an undo file

Tags: vim

I have a vim file where every time I open it, it gives me a red message:

```
E823: Not an undo file: <filename>
```

Followed by:

```
Press ENTER of type command to continue
```

Doesn't appear to be an error, but it is very annoying. I've read about persisted undo files in newer versions of vim. But I don't know how it relates to this. So:
- What is this trying to tell me?
- How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Posting as a comment as there isn't enough info, so it's just a guess. Looks like there's a leftover undo file for the specific file you're editing, but it's empty. Check for files ending in `~` in the file folder or, if you have persistent undo enable, in the `undodir` directory. If it's really empty, you can safely remove it to get rid of the error message.

Comment: Hey, that worked. Thank you! You can post as answer if you like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like there's a leftover undo file for the specific file you're editing, but it's empty.

Check for files ending in `~` in the file folder or, if you have persistent undo enable, in the  `undodir` directory (should be in your `.vimrc` if configured).

If it's really empty, you can safely remove it to get rid of the error message.

Comment: Is there a way to tell vim to remove it automatically?